# Is there a way to do a PUT with WebClient?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, webclient

with the WebClient class in .NET 4.0, is there a way to do a PUT?

I know you can do a GET with DownloadString() and a POST with UploadString(), but is there a method or property that lets you do a PUT?

Thanks.

Comment: Now that is an entirely different question, i do not think that it would make sense to answer that here!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are overloads for `UploadString` that let you specify the method.  For example, [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144237.aspx) takes a `Uri`, a `string` for the method, and a `string` for the data.

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.UploadString(apiUrl, 
        WebRequestMethods.Http.Put, // or simply use "PUT"
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload))
}
```

Comment: can u give any example?

Comment: `client.UploadString(apiUrl, "PUT", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload))`

Answer (score 11):

You can use [webclient.UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k.aspx)(urlwithparams,"Put","")

url with params should include the params in querystring format ...
urlwithparams = www.foo.com?key=value&key2=value2

This worked for me...

Comment: Does the PUT should be in all capital? secondly the last parameter in the uploadstring is "" why?

Answer (score 1):

Huh? As stated on MS's website [WebClient.UploadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktfa4fek.aspx) does take the method (as a string) too right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -3):

I don't think that WebClient can do it. However, you can use the [HttpWebrequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class to [perform a put request](http://vinothnat.blogspot.com/2007/09/httpwebrequest-using-put-method.html).

Comment: The second link appears to be broken, here is a copy of the code posted by the author; https://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/03/26/put-request-with-httpwebrequest/

Comment: WebClient can indeed do it. You just have to specify the method (PUT).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144237(v=vs.110).aspx