# C# customize HTTPWebrequest Initial line

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, upnp, dlna

I want to implement a SOAP request using C# HttpWebrequest.

I am stock at customizing the initial line.
Is there a  simple solution or a work around?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST /_urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ContentDirectory_control HTTP/1.1";
```

I want the initial Header line received by the Server to look like

```
POST /_urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ContentDirectory_control HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering from '[Is there a way to do a PUT with WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346750/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-put-with-webclient)',

There are overloads for UploadString that let you specify the method. For example, `WebClient.UploadString` Method takes a Uri, a string for the method, and a string for the data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144237.aspx