# UploadString of Webclient for using PUT method

Tags: c#, rest, webclient, http-method, uploadstring

I want to Update data using **webclient UploadString** method. The following code gives error saying,

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

```
var syncClient = new WebClient();
string URI = "https://test-khalid.herokuapp.com/v1/roles/de988992-4db8-4f75-884b-3dba893310e6";
syncClient.Headers.Add("authorization", "invalid-token");
Response.Write(syncClient.UploadString(URI, "PUT", "{\"title\":\"Shomaail Title 1\", \"role_type\":\"3\" }"));
```

I wrote the above code following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346750/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-put-with-webclient). Please let me know the answer?

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanatory, it's saying the server says that method is not allowed.

Comment: Did you try just sending as `post`? And why are you adding an "invalid-token" as the autorization header?

Comment: Invalid token does not matter, I tried sending as post it works. then i found out that I have to send it as PATCH according to the configuration of server

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved using PATCH command instead of PUT. In the server PATCH is specified for update not PUT